# Android proguard issues for release

Tags: android, proguard

I'm able to create builds for my android app, but when I turn on proguard i'm getting numerouos warnings, and then the build fails. The warnings are like the ones below:

```
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
```

It's complaining about libraries that were used in my project. My settings are below:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        proguardFile file('proguard-rules.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Within my `proguard-rules.txt` I have the following:

```
-libraryjars libs
```

All of my libraries are stored in the libs folder. Is there anything else i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inspect the jars , creating a packages list in libs you are using.

Then try adding following for those packages in the list in your proguard config file:

```
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**

...

-keep        class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your libraries contain duplicates of the android.http classes, which are already present in the Android runtime. This may cause conflicts. You should remove the duplicate libraries from your project.

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: library class ... depends on program class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)