# How to keep crosswalk code when obfuscate my project?

Tags: android, proguard

I import crosswalk in my app. To keep the crosswalk code, I add this in proguard-project.txt:

```
-dontwarn org.chromium.**
-dontwarn org.xwalk.core.**

-keep class com.google.common.** {*;}
-keep class com.googlecode.eyesfree.braille.** {*;}
-keep class javax.annotation.** {*;}
-keep class org.chromium.** {*;}
-keep class org.xwalk.core.** {*;}
```

But, it seems wrong. Who can help me? Thanks very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469560/android-proguard-issues-for-release/25470047#25470047  same type issue.

Answer (score 5):

found this:

```
-keep class org.xwalk.core.** {
*;
}
-keep class org.chromium.** {
*;
}
-keepattributes **
```

from here:

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

You need add another statement:

```
-keepattributes *
```

Comment: I solved this problem by moving the code to the header of '-keep class' regions. Sorry for my pool English. :(

Comment: @frank_hust any examples?